# How is the Take() method working with IAsyncEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, .net-6.0, iasyncenumerable

I have been recently playing around with IAsyncEnumerables and there is a certain thing that I can't understand how it works behind the scenes.

Consider the following piece of code:

```
private async Task Test()
{
    var t = new List<int>();

    await foreach (var number in Numbers().Take(5).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        t.Add(number);
    }
}

int[] myIntArray = new int[10] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

private async IAsyncEnumerable<int> Numbers()
{
    foreach (var element in myIntArray)
    {
        yield return element;
    }
}
```

So what bothers me is, how does the **IAsyncEnumerable** method knows how to only execute 5 times, or in other words, how does it translate the **.Take(5)** method in such way that it can take the number passed into account when executing?

Comment: Do you understand how the non-async version works, and how you might implement it? I'd expect the async version to work in the same way - it only "asks" the underlying sequence for the given number of elements (one at a time, yielding them as it receives them).

Comment: There is not framework-provided LINQ methods for async enumerables AFAIK. So it depends on how the `Take` is implemented. But it should work basically as any other enumerable in this case by lazily loading data when needed.

Comment: Are you using `System.Linq.Async`? In that case you can inspect the code in the Github repo. You can do the same with LINQ or any other C# class. All are open source and developed (not just stored) in Github

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IAsyncEnumerable<T>` is a simple interface with a single method defined - [`IAsyncEnumerable<T>.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerable-1.getasyncenumerator?view=net-8.0) which returns  [`IAsyncEnumerator<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerator-1?view=net-8.0) which is not that much more complicated - it has [`MoveNextAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerator-1.movenextasync?view=net-8.0) method (advances the enumerator asynchronously to the next element of the collection) and [`Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerator-1.current?view=net-8.0) property (gets the element in the collection at the current position of the enumerator), which is similar to "ordinary" `IEnumerable<T>`. In the nutshell all LINQ methods will operate with those two (if we don't take into account some optimizations for some corner cases).

There is no framework-provided LINQ for async enumerables AFAIK. If you are using one from the [`System.Linq.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/) from [reactive extensions](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) then it is implemented basically the same as the "ordinary" `Take`, which wraps the source enumerable into special "partitioner" class with overloaded `MoveNext` ([source code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Partition.SpeedOpt.cs,338)). In case of async enumerables it is `AsyncEnumerablePartition` ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/2305a5b0e58b41326e952ca91f004e7c3e5d0bff/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/AsyncEnumerablePartition.cs#L133)) which on materialization will basically call `await MoveNextAsync(...)` until the requested limit is reached (i.e. passed to the `Take`) and then will stop the execution. A simplified version can look something like the following:

```
public static class Exts
{
    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<int> Take(this IAsyncEnumerable<int> source, int n)
    {
        var enumerator = source.GetAsyncEnumerator();
        while (n > 0)
        {
            if (await enumerator.MoveNextAsync())
            {
                yield return enumerator.Current;
                n--;
            }
            else
            {
                yield break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that actual behavior will depend on the async enumerable itself, i.e. for example if it is loading data in batches then it will need to load a whole batch first.

Comment: OMG, I needed 4 attempts to implement `Take`.

Comment: @Sinatr it seems that you have discovered yet another variation of [FizzBuzz](https://wiki.c2.com/?FizzBuzzTest) =) Based on your first implementation - I made a similar error in my original take (not shown here) =)

Comment: The documentation for System.Linq.Async and Rx.NET is so lacking, it's easier to read the code directly

Comment: Never heard about FizzBuzz, but if you search for "c# pattern matching divisible", then for some wierd reason `FizzBuzz` solution video is the first match.. kek.

Comment: Hey  @GuruStron , thank you for the answer! It was really helpful. Now that I've read through the AsyncEnumerablePartition source code and I've also seen what .Take() does behind the scenes it's much clearer. I am using the System.Linq.Async extensions, so like you said, it basically returns a new AsyncEnumerablePartition and it sets the maxIndexInclusive property. I guess we then have the MoveNextCore() method inside the AsyncEnumerablePartition which will check if the the number of enumerations is greater than the _maxIndexInclusive and the call enumerator.MoveNextAsync().